# NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption LIKE example in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently, I'm using for searching data from Object using rangeOfString as follow. Result is displayed all data contain 'ab' when I type 'ab' in TextField. What I want is I want to display all data starting 'ab' when I type 'ab'. Please let me know how to do just SQL query like `'LIKE 'ab%''`

```
    for (ContactObject* nsObj in _objects) {
        NSRange nameRange = [nsObj.title rangeOfString:finalSearchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || phoneRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [_filteredTableData addObject:nsObj];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use predicate

```
  NSArray *filteredObjects = [_objects
      filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title BEGINSWITH[c] %@)",
                                           finalSearchString]];
```